# How to make right side sidebar hover over the context of page instead of taking separate space

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website and I am facing an issue in sidebar. I wanna create a sidebar on the right side which hovers from right side to left and shows the full content when courser is moved over it. very similar to the sidebar in https://www.psx.com.pk.
I created a hovering sidebar on right side which is working fine. But now I am facing issue as it needs a separate space to hover while I want it to hover over my content of page. Like one I mentioned in the link https://www.psx.com.pk.

This is my side bar code

```
<head>
    <style>
        #sidebar-body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .sidebar {
            /*background: #42b078;*/
            position: relative;
            right: -260px;
            width: 450px;
            height: 180px;
            transition: all 0.3s;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
        }

        .sidebar:hover {
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="sidebar-body">
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Library</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Applications</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And I am using it like this in my full Laravel page

```
 <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Entity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Industry</th>
                    <th scope="col">Rating Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Dissemination Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Long Term Rating</th>
                    <th scope="col">Short Term Rating</th>
                    <th scope="col">Outlook</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
@include('includes.sidebar')

     </div>
```

Its Appearing like this on my page [mypageIMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaOnt.png)

While I want it to appear like this [SampleImg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqCcJ.png) [SampleImg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUNlt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position error is due to `.sidebar {position: relative;}`

change it to `{position: fixed}` since you want your sidebar to always fix on the desired location.

Adjust the `width` and `right` to ideally show your icons only when it's not hovered.

http://jsfiddle.net/8doa3nvg/2/ Here is the jsfiddle code snippet based on your code sample.

Depending on what you want to do with your blade view. Just want to suggest you that you might need to create your sidebar responsively for all devices since hover is not available in mobile.

Comment: Thanks dear position of my sidebar is fixed now. But sidebar becomes invisible under the page content and becomes visible when it gets a free space on a page. I want it to display on top of the content. How could I do that?

Comment: @Asad did you set `z-index: 99999`

Comment: @Awais just set it it working fine now thank you so much

Comment: Cheers! you find my comment helpful :)